# Get the count of the each date entry from onr of the raw from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I am working on getting values and creating a chart from CSV file using python.
How to get the number of entry of the each date? For Example, sample Date row:

```
4/14/2016  11:05:15 AM
4/14/2016  09:06:15 PM
6/14/2016  11:05:15 AM
```

It should gives an output as

```
4/14/2016 entry 2 times
6/14/2016 entry 1 time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
with open("your_file.csv") as f:
    for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(map(str.split, f.read().strip().split("\n"))), key = lambda x:x[0]):
        print x,len(list(y))
```

output

```
4/14/2016 2
6/14/2016 1
```

Another way: if csv contains empty lines

```
with open("your_file.csv") as f:
    my_list = []
    for line in f:
        if line:
            my_list.append(line.strip().split())
    for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0]):
        print x, len(list(y))
```

Comment: Thanks :) works fine with the small amount (tested on 10 entries) of entries of csv. but for 150 entries below line gives and error "IndexError: list index out of range" `for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(map(str.split, f.read().strip().split("\n"))), key = lambda x:x[0]):`

Answer (score 1):

Simply count the dates:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
with open('somefile.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
   for row in reader:
      c.update(row[0])

for date,count in c.most_common():
   print('{} {}'.format(date, count))
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? It gave me the output :

    / 6
    1 6
    4 5
    6 4
    0 3
    2 3

Comment: It will work if your csv is formatted as you mentioned;  you need to adjust the delimiter based on what it is in your file. In my example, the delimiter is a tab `\t`.

Comment: I think it still does not work and you should change `row[0]` as `row[0:1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` to get the values as well the count:

```
import collections

d=collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('data', 'r') as f:
    for line in map(lambda line:line.strip(), f.readlines()):
        row=line.split()
        d[row[0]].append(row[1])
print(d)
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key+' has the following '+str(len(value))+' entries/entry: '+str(value))
```

Output:

```
$ cat data 
4/14/2016  11:05:15 AM
4/14/2016  09:06:15 PM
6/14/2016  11:05:15 AM
$ python p.py 
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'4/14/2016': ['11:05:15', '09:06:15'], '6/14/2016': ['11:05:15']})
4/14/2016 has the following 2 entries/entry: ['11:05:15', '09:06:15']
6/14/2016 has the following 1 entries/entry: ['11:05:15']
```